# How do I allow only a comma to be last character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this:

```
ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[,\/-](?:\s)*[a-zA-Z0-9]*)*$/"
```

This matches even `fada/`, `fada-`. I need it to match only if it's `fada,` and for `/` and `-` there has to be something that follows it.

[regexr.com/3u1d0](http://regexr.com/3u1d0)

Comment: Change `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` to `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`, `ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[,\/-]\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$/"`

Comment: What are the actual rules?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the string can(not must) contain a `/` or `-` or `,` in between characters. if there's a `/` or `-` it must be followed by some character..it cannot be the last. But if it's a `,` at the end it's ok

Comment: Try [`^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[,\/-]\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*,?$`](https://regex101.com/r/8FGN1Y/1)

Comment: I understand `,` cannot be at the start of the string, but you may just add `,?` after `^` to allow it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[,\/-]~\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*,?$
```

See the [pattern demo](https://regex101.com/r/8FGN1Y/2/)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - 1+ ASCII alphanumeric chars
- `(?:[,\/-]\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` - zero or more consecutive sequences of:

  - `[,\/-]` - a `,`, `/` or `-`
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - 1+ ASCII alphanumeric chars
- `,?` - an optional (one or zero) comma
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: hey..the pattern in answer and in demo is different.. also it does not accept `fa da`..so i added a `\s` ..is that right? after adding `'s` : `ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[,\/\-\s] *[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*,?$/"`

Comment: @DwightSchrute Yes, your enhancement will work. A demo is not a proof, it just shows how this posted pattern is going to work against *separate* standalone strings. In the demo, there is only one multiline string, hence `\s` (that matches vertical whitespace, too) is replaced with a regular space. Also, you may probably use [`^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[,\/-]?\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*,?$`](https://regex101.com/r/8FGN1Y/3).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `|` to separate the pattern for `,` from `[\/-]` instead:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:,$|(?:[\/-]\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$)/
```

Comment: hey..thanks but this does not match if there's something after the `,`